# How to use a data source created in one application by another application in wso2 cloud?

Tags: wso2, wso2-cloud

Is it possible to create a data source inside an application (as a resource) and then use that same data source in another application within the same organization

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Reason for this is, [WSO2 Cloud](https://cloud.wso2.com) (App Cloud to be precise) having an application level resource isolation. So, if you create a data source as a resource in one application, it is not visible to another application even within the same organization.

One thing you can do is, create another data source in your next application for the same database.